# Touch event not triggered on a QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I am currently implementing a QML application for a touch device with openGL rendering in the background. I used this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYa5DLV6ADQ as a base for my work.

In short, I am using a custom QQuickView and set the option "clearbeforerendering" to false to be able to draw my openGL content. In addition to that, I want to receive touchEvents in my custom QQuickView to modify my openGL rendering in real time.

Unfornately, touchEvent is never triggered, while I receive correctly the different mouseEvents. I tried this code on a QOPenGLWindow and received the touchEvents correctly, so the problem doesn't come from my device.

Here are some part of my code which could be of help:

main.cpp

```
#include "tableclothwindow.h"
#include "target.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDesktopWidget dw;
    TableclothWindow *mainWindow = new TableclothWindow();

    mainWindow->setMinimumSize(QSize(dw.width(),dw.height()));
    mainWindow->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    mainWindow->show();
    mainWindow->initializeQMLInteraction();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
Item
{
    id: container
    Text {
        objectName: "text"
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello world!"
        x: 100
        y: 80
        color: "#00FF00"
        opacity: 0.8
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
        MouseArea{
            onClicked: helloText.color = "FF0000"
        }
    }
}
```

tablecloth.cpp (custom QQuickView)

```
#include "tableclothwindow.h"
#include "tableclothscene.h"

TableclothWindow::TableclothWindow(QWindow *parent)
    :QQuickView(parent),
      m_mousePressed(false),
      m_firstTime(true),
      m_targetCentroid(QPointF(0,0)),
      m_scene(new TableclothScene)
{
    // disable auto-clear for manual openGL rendering
    setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), SLOT(renderOpenGLScene()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    // update visuals
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    m_timer->start(30);
}

TableclothWindow::~TableclothWindow()
{

}

// openGL rendering functions
void TableclothWindow::renderOpenGLScene()
{
    if(m_firstTime){
        m_scene->initialize();
        m_scene->resize(width(),height());
        assignLinkedPointMass();
        m_firstTime = false;
    }
    m_scene->render();
}

void TableclothWindow::update()
{
    if(!m_firstTime){
        updateTargetPosition();
        m_scene->update();
        QQuickView::update();
    }
}

// event handling
// working
void TableclothWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();
    qDebug() << "mouse pressed"

}

// Doesn't work 
void TableclothWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();
    qDebug() << " touch detected";
 }
```

Does anyone knows why the touchEvents are not triggered in the custom QQuickView ?

Answer (score 5):

After some research I found that the touchEvents were not dispatch in the QQuickView, despite what is said in the Qt documenttation.

To solve the problem I had to handle the touchEvents in the Qt event dispatcher of the QWindow ( which QQuickView inherit from ) QWindow::event(Event*). I guess you can propagate the event yourself or use it as it is in the event function but I wonder if it's a bug or an oversight.

Here is the code I ended it up with, I don't know if it is clean but it works..

```
    bool TableclothWindow::event(QEvent *event)
    {
         event->accept();
         if(event->type() == QEvent::TouchEvent){
             QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent*>(event);
             //handling the touchEvent 
         }
         return QQuickView::event(event);
     }
```

Hope it might help someone even if the question have been down voted with no reason given.